# embedding jquery.prettyPhoto causes script to show on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, minify, prettyphoto

When I move:

```
<script src="js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
```

To:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   ...
</script>
```

Then the script starts showing on the page from the **bold** part onwards:

style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:500px; height:23px;" allowTransparency="true">**'},s);var o=this,u=false,a,f,l,c,h,p,d=e(window).height(),v=e...**

The script is attributed with this information:

```
Class: prettyPhoto
Use: Lightbox clone for jQuery
Author: Stephane Caron (http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com)
Version: 3.1.5
```

How can I move the script from a `.js` file to the page [correctly](https://jsfiddle.net/rL9h958e/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the content of a `javascript` contains the closing script tag `</script>` it can cause the browser's parser to interpret wrongly the script block code.

The code here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("</script>");
</script>
```

Will not work and the output you will see in the browser will be

```
");
```

As if the browser read the script block as

```
**script start tag ->** <script type="text/javascript">
    alert("</script> **<- script end tag**
```

## The Solution

There are two known solutions for having the `<script>...</script>` string inside a script block:

1. Break the string into two separate string and concatenate them using `+`

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("<scr"+"ipt>...</scr"+ "ipt>");
</script>
```

2. Wrap the whole script code block with comment block code:

```html
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
        alert("<script></script>");
        -->
    </script>
```

> Note that the second example will **NOT WORK** if you only have the closing-tag, since the browser will tag that closing string as the tag that was supposed to close your original opening `<scrip>` tag.

This example will not work:

```html
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
        alert("</script>");
        -->
    </script>
```

Specifically for your code - [this is the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/heuy6po0/) that fixes it.

Answer (score 2):

No errors. https://jsfiddle.net/rL9h958e/1/

The script had a plethora of = = problems as well as bad html.

Social_Tools looks fishy in all cases,

```
social_tools:'<div class="twitter"><a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="none">Tweet</a></div>' + 
            '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></div>' +
                     '<div class="facebook">
```

Answer (score 1):

is your page html4 or html5?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
```

html5 you don't need to use type=

```
<script src="javascript.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed it but the code is still appearing on the page

Comment: can you link to the page?

Comment: you have the <script src= and the javescript embedded in the html, it's the same code, either link to <script src=" or embed it

Comment: I commented the link out. It's just there for reference. The embedded version is causing an issue though as you can see.

Comment: use a validator, there are problems in your code https://validator.w3.org/nu/ also in your code do you have '<!DOCTYPE html>' as the top line or just the '<html>' that I see in the jsfiddle?

Comment: this one give you an clean up with html tidy, so you can use that too https://validator.w3.org/  but save your orignal file also to refer to